# Updating website through heroku flask application

Tags: git, heroku, flask

I used the following tutorial on github:
https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku

To make my own personal website. However, after going through all the steps, buying a domain name and everything else, I'm not sure how to make changes to the site. I have altered the files in my flask_heroku folder, such as with the favicon.ico, and altering the html files but when I tried to make a commit through my git gui I realized I was making changes to the master branch...

I hope that makes sense. I'm relatively new to web development, and now I'm really stuck.

So my main question is how do I make edits to my newly 'blank' website?

---

UPDATE: This is what happens when I try `$ git push heroku master` from the command line.

```
 Downloading/unpacking bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
     Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified bonjour-py to allow).
   Cleaning up...
   No distributions at all found for bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
   Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Comment: What's the problem with making changes to your `master` branch? Typically, to update a Heroku site you would modify your files locally, commit (often to `master`), and then push to Heroku.

Comment: I don't have a problem doing that. It just looks like the changes are being applied to the program file alongside contributors making bug fixes and what not. And so I didn't know If I was interferring with that, or actually making changes to my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you should have two remotes:

- `origin` which points to the original github repo i.e. https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku.git
- `heroku` which points to your heroku app

If you want to keep your changes separate from the `master` branch, create a new branch called `production`:

```
git checkout -B production
```

You are now tracking your code changes in the production branch, which is what you'll push to heroku:

```
echo "Hello, world!" > /some/file
git add /some/file
git commit -m "Hello world"
git push heroku production:master
```

That last line deploys your production branch to heroku, replacing the master branch on heroku.

Now if you want to sync up your code with updates from the original authors:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout production
git merge master
```

This merges the changed master files into your production branch.

UPDATE: regarding Heroku rejecting your push, it's because bonjour-py isn't available in pip. Are you sure this module is required for your app? Folks here seem to think no: [Heroku push fails repeatedly, appears to fail on installing Bonjour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917628/heroku-push-fails-repeatedly-appears-to-fail-on-installing-bonjour)

Try removing it from your requirements.txt.

Comment: Thank you!! Well said, I'll test it out once I resolve how to deploy the python app.

Comment: See my update regarding your rejected heroku push. Others have seen this error too and the solution is to remove the package from the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @RKBWS47 I appreciate the help and I checked it out.. Seems like it would fix my problem, although I've followed every step, tried manually removing bonjour-py from the requirements.txt file but all to no avail. I've been troubleshooting this problem for 3 days now and with no results I think I'm going to have to uninstall the package and redo everything from the beginning again.

Comment: @jeskah are you committing the changes to requirements.txt before deploying to Heroku? make edits / `git add requirements.txt` / `git commit -m 'removing bonjour from requirements'` / `git push heroku production:master`

Comment: @jeskah In any case, it's likely there was a problem with your virtual env if something went awry in requirements.txt, so restarting from scratch may be the better option. **If my answer above helped you with the original question, please press the check mark next to it to accept the answer.**

Comment: 3rd attempt, had to delete the program again. I think something is really wrong with the repository and the programs associated, not at all up to date. I took your advice removed bonjour, then tried to git push like you said, and it returned that the files had been edited and it couldn't follow through. So I had to delete it. But I will check off your answer, thank you for all the help!!