# Heroku build fail due to bonjour even after removing bonjour from my requirements

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having an error when I am pushing my app to heroku , it says their is a build error with bonjour listed even though I removed bonjour from my requirements. I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks below is my output from the terminal.

```
castdrop ryan$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10905, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5108/5108), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10905/10905), 11.89 MiB | 6.41 MiB/s, done.
Total 10905 (delta 4362), reused 10905 (delta 4362)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.13
remote: -----> Noticed cffi. Bootstrapping libffi.
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:        Collecting altgraph==0.10.2 (from -r /tmp/build_0a1d196bd08bbb874d8bde1a1990ff5f/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading altgraph-0.10.2.tar.gz (481kB)
remote:        Collecting bdist-mpkg==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_0a1d196bd08bbb874d8bde1a1990ff5f/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading bdist_mpkg-0.5.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_0a1d196bd08bbb874d8bde1a1990ff5f/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_0a1d196bd08bbb874d8bde1a1990ff5f/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_0a1d196bd08bbb874d8bde1a1990ff5f/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to floating-temple-76589.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/floating-temple-76589.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/floating-temple-76589.git'
Ryans-MacBook-Air:castdrop ryan$   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bonjour-py==0.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push fails repeatedly, appears to fail on installing Bonjour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917628/heroku-push-fails-repeatedly-appears-to-fail-on-installing-bonjour)

Comment: Although I have removed this from my requirements heroku still attempts to include bonjour in the build

Comment: I have tried the various solutions and used py-complie with no sucess